# Using video.js with dynamically created video tags

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

I'm currently using video.js to handle flash fallback from html5 video.  When a user clicks a thumbnail on my site, I dynamically (with js/jquery) create and insert the required html into a jquery ui dialog window, which then displays the video, either using html5 or flash fall-back.  Here is the relevant code:

```
    //setup jquery ui dialog window 
    $( "div#video_box" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            close: function() {
                $("video").remove()
            }
         });

    //the following code runs after a video thumbnail click event.  
{
    var $videoBox = $("div#video_box"),
    url = VIDEOSTORAGE + id ,  //url to s3 storage bucket + id of the video/thumbnail that was clicked
    html ="";
    html += "<video id='downloadedVideo_"+id+"' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' width='320' height='240' controls preload='auto' width='640' height='264' poster='"+PHOTOSTORAGEMEDIUM + id'>";
    html += "<source src='"+url+".mp4' type='video/mp4' />";
    html += "</video>";
    $videoBox.html(html);
    $("#downloadedVideo_"+id).load();
    $videoBox.dialog( "open" );
    _V_("downloadedVideo_"+id);  //initialize video player
}
```

This code works perfectly on all browsers the first time that a video thumbnail is clicked.  My bug triggers when a user clicks on the video thumbnail for a video that he has already watched.

In FF I'm getting a "no video with supported mime type is found" error on the second pass.  Both chrome and safari load and play the video on the second pass; but do so using their default html5 player rather than the video.js player.

I think that my problem is that video.js must be initialized using unique video-tag ids, and the second time a user clicks a video thumbnail my code tries to initialize the player with a video-tag id that it has already used.

Does anyone know a clean way to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating only one video player instance (instead of a new instance per each new video).  I then dynamically change that player's src attribute using video.js' src method.

First I created an initialized a global variable to hold the video player instance (`var videoPlayer =  _V_("downloadedVideo)`).  Then I replaced my old video thumbnail click event code with the following:

```
`           var $videoBox = $("div#video_box"),
                url = VIDEOSTORAGE + id + "/" + encodeURI(post.video_file_name.split(".")[0]);    
            $videoBox.dialog('option', 'title', post.video_file_name);
            $videoBox.dialog('option', 'position', ["center", 100]);
            $videoBox.dialog( 'open' );
            $(video).attr('poster', PHOTOSTORAGEMEDIUM + id + "/" + post.photo_file_name);
            videoPlayer.src({type: 'video/mp4', src: url + '.mp4'});`
```

Now video.js is working on all modern browsers EXCEPT mobile safari.  For some reason that I can't figure out, mobile safari won't load/play any videos.  I just get a blank player with the "loading" image going around in a circle.  It won't even load the image at the poster attribute.  I might make a separate post on this later today.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like the player is only recognized the first time it is rendered so you'll need ur code to acknowledge that its a videoJS player every time that player HTML is loaded into the DOM.

Looks like chuck has it.  Otherwise:

what I do is load the player into the DOM once, hide it if not needed, show it when loading new src for play.

Hope this helps!